# Where to find the number of active concurrent invocations in Google Cloud Functions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am looking for a way to see how **many concurrent invocations** there are active at any point in time, e.g. in a minute range. I am looking for this as I received the error:

> Forbidden: 403 Exceeded rate limits: too many concurrent queries for
>   this project_and_region. For more information, see
>   https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/

The quotas are listed here: https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas

I am fine with having quotas, but I would like to see this number in a chart. Where can I find this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there is no way of seeing that information directly. There is a workaround though. You can do as follows:

1. Go to Google Cloud Console > Stackdriver Logging
2. At the text box that says "Filter by label or text search", click on the small arrow at the end of the text box.
3. Choose "Convert to advanced filter"
4. Type that query inside:

```
resource.type="cloud_function"
resource.labels.function_name="[GOOGLE_CLOUD_FUNCTION_NAME]"
"Function execution started"
```

5. At "Last hour" drop down menu, choose "Custom"
6. Fix the start and end time

This will list all the times that the Cloud Function was executed in the time range. If it was executed multiple times, instead of counting one by one you can use the following Python script:

- Open Google Cloud Shell
- Install Google Cloud Logging Library `$ pip install google-cloud-logging`
- Create a `main.py` file using [my GitHub code example](https://github.com/andrikosrikos/Google-Cloud-Support/blob/master/Stackdriver_Logging/list_logs_within_timestamp.py). (I have tested it and it is working as expected)
- Change the **date_a_str** and set it as start date.
- Change the **date_b_str** and set it as end date.
- In `function_name = "[CLOUD_FUNCTION_NAME]"` change **[CLOUD_FUNCTION_NAME]** to the name of your Cloud Function.
- Execute the Python code `$ python main.py`
- You should see a response as follows:

```
Found entries: [XX]
Waiting up to 5 seconds.
Sent all pending logs.
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, and your python code, @Andrei. I just want to add for future reference, Stackdriver is now called Metrics Explorer, and they have made it easier to determine the number of invocations directly in the console. https://console.cloud.google.com/monitoring/metrics-explorer